# Error at the transport level when sending a request to the server

Tags: .net, asp.net, sql, sql-server

Strange System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException

**Error at the transport level when sending a request to the server. (Provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - Since both ends of the canal there are no processes.)**

I've got this exception on my Web Site every time after restarting my SqlServer on simple request like this :

```
if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
```

but after I do refresh the page with this codebehind error disappears.

How to handle this error and where it comes from ?

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If connection pooling is enabled check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx > Removing Connections.

> If a connection already existing in
> the pool becomes invalid (a server
> restart can cause this) the first
> attempt to use that results in an
> exception (only then is the invalid
> connection removed from the pool)

You would have to do a ClearAllPools or ClearPool (Clearing the Pool section) on the application server when you restart the SQL server.

**Reference**

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/spike/a-transport-level-error-has-occurred-when-sending-the-request-to-the-server-provider-tcp-provider-error-0-an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host)